# What's this infinite sum?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

In a German science journal I read that PH Schoute asked this in the Educational Times around 1900:

What is the sum of

$$S = \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2+3}+\frac{1}{4+5+6}+\frac{1}{7+8+9+10} +\cdots\text{?}$$

I don't know if an answer has been found. Anyone?

Comment: A question about the same series on [math.se]: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/78292

Comment: In other words, compute $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac2{n(n^2+1)}$$

Comment: ... which is $2 \gamma + 2 \text{Re}(\Psi(i))$.

Comment: Thanks so far ... :-)
My computer says it is roughly 1,3437 ...
Robert?

Comment: @RobertIsrael : If you write `2\gamma + 2\operatorname{Re}(\Psi(i))` you will see $2\gamma + 2\operatorname{Re}(\Psi(i)),$ with proper spacing between $2$ and $\operatorname{Re}$. With `\operatorname`, the horizontal spacing varies appropriately with the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a very good approximation of the partial sums writing first
$$\frac2{n(n^2+1)}=\frac 2{n(n+i)(n-i)}=\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n-i}-\frac{1}{n+i}.$$
Using generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p\frac2{n(n^2+1)}=2 H_p-H_{p-i}-H_{p+i}+H_i+H_{-i}.$$
Using asymptotics
$$S_p=\left(H_{-i}+H_i\right)-\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}
   {p^3}-\frac{1}{p^5}+\frac{2}{3
   p^6}+\frac{1}{p^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^8}\right).$$ As @Robert Israel wrote in [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443247/whats-this-infinite-sum#comment1144169_443247)
$$\left(H_{-i}+H_i\right)=2 \gamma + 2 \text{Re}(\Psi(i)).$$